# Would running an air conditioner close to an Ink Jet printer cause a loss in printer quality?

Tags: printing, printer

I have an air-conditioner that I use to cool off the room I put my computers in, and near by is my Ink Jet printer, an HP Office Jet 4622.  Since we've gotten closer to winter and the air has become drier, I've noticed that the print quality is going all streaky even with the new cartridge.  The longer it sits unused the more this seems to be the case.  Is it possible the air conditioner is causing this?  Or is it just an old printer?

Comment: Usually if I clean the cartridge it starts printing again, but doesn't solve the overall issue.

Comment: Also the brand new cartridge has Jun 2018 as it's expiration date.

Comment: Inkjets do not like sitting idle. Unless they're used, the nozzles will dry out and that's why they so often want to clean themselves. A dry atmosphere could make this worse. Expiration dates only apply if the cartridge has not been opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike laser printer which has powder, ink jet printer is liquid based and moisture affects its quality. The air conditioner not only cools the air but removes humidity from air.

This is because if the air is humid, we tend to sweat more. We do sweat on a less humid environment but then the sweat will evaporate faster and we don’t really feel it.

So to the answer, air conditioner promotes more evaporation of water in ink and this might affect the quality.

> Inkjet Printing The inkjet printing process prefers 45 to 55 percent
> relative humidity. This is the standard range for most inkjet printing
> paper, and to vary from this range can cause ink spreading (in which
> inkjet dots expand rather than staying crisp and precisely
> positioned).

<sup>Source: https://www.printindustry.com/Newsletters/Newsletter-205.aspx</sup>